# Spring boot response caching

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching

I was trying to understand the caching that happens at the client side.
Unfortunately I am unable to find any resources that can help me out.

I have employee model objects which are fairly small in size.
Once a use a GET request to obtain an employee object, I want it to be cached at the client side
Now when the request comes again to obtain the same employee, I want to see if the actual object has been modified, if not, then serve from the client cache else return the modified object also adding it to the cache.

I am using Spring boot to create a REST endpoint.
What I have been able to figure out is that cache-control would be used some how, but I am not sure how the objects would be added here in spring.

Any help here is much appreciated!!!!

Thanks,

Amar

Answer (score 0):

HTTP caching is not an easy topic. There are different ways to do it, and you should probably start by familiarizing yourself with the mechanisms, this seems to be a good starting resource: [HTTP caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching)

Then, you will probably identify some common usage patterns you will want to reuse. One way to do that is to create custom annotations and [write an interceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) that reacts on them.

For example, you could write such an annotation:

```
@Inherited
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface CacheFor {
    long amount();
    TimeUnit unit() default TimeUnit.SECONDS;
}
```

and use it on controller methods like this:

```
@CacheFor(amount=10, unit = MINUTES)
@RequestMapping(bla bla)
public FooBar serveMyData(){
  // code here
}
```

and in your interceptor, you will need to look at the handler method, check whether it has this annotation, and if it does, set the appropriate headers.